# How can I inject some code in methods start and end

Tags: java, android

I want to inject code in methods at compile time. I tried `aspectj` but it have problems. I cannot make it work properly. Also it is poorly supported in Android Studio. 
example of what I want-

Before compilation

```
public void doSomething() {
       doing..
}
```

After Compiling the code should look

```
public void doSomething() {
       code injected here
       doing..
       code injected here
 }
```

how can I do something like annotate the method `@aroundMethod` and it can generate that code

Comment: `aspecj` (and any other DI tool) can only inject code before and after a particular method is called, not within its body. Still, if you have access to the source code, you can create a parser that will scan for particular methods and inject code where needed (prior to it being compiled)

Comment: `after a particular method is called` means we can not know if the method got executed?

Comment: https://github.com/gybin02/jet-aop it is doing same what i want. but with aspectj can I do it using dagger?

Comment: `after a particular method is called`. No, it's quite the opposite. Suppose that you have complete control over `class A`. By, complete control I mean that you know exactly when a particular method is called as well when it returns. Now, it's pretty trivial to add some code before it's called and after it returns but you can't add code in the middle of the method, can you.

Comment: That link is in Chinese.

Comment: Please, clarify where the injected code should be, inside the method or before and after it's called?

Comment: @dsp_user please use chrome translator. Yes I want the code to execute before and after the method. I tried all aspectj plugin but they are not working with android studio > 3.0 databinding and java 8 combine.

Answer (score 0):

AspectJ is used for this kind of things. Here is a nice Android example how to do aspects in the Android world: https://github.com/firstthumb/AspectJ-Android-Example

One example from their code:

```
package android.mobile.peakgames.net.aspectjandroid.aspect;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.*;

@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {
    private static final String TAG = LoggingAspect.class.getName();

    @Pointcut("execution(* android.view.View.OnClickListener.onClick(..))")
    public void onClickEntryPoint() {
    }

    @Before("onClickEntryPoint()")
    public void onClickBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Before Advice ==> Clicked on : " + ((Button)joinPoint.getArgs()[0]).getText());
    }

    @Around("onClickEntryPoint()")
    public void onClickAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Log.d(TAG, "Around Advice ==> Clicked on : " + ((Button)joinPoint.getArgs()[0]).getText());

        joinPoint.proceed();
    }

    @After("onClickEntryPoint()")
    public void onClickAfter(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        Log.d(TAG, "After Advice ==> Clicked on : " + ((Button)joinPoint.getArgs()[0]).getText());
    }

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "onClickEntryPoint()")
    public void onClickAfterReturning() {
        Log.d(TAG, "AfterReturning Advice ==>");
    }
}
```

In general, the idea is to register an aspect class with something like @Aspect and then define when a particular method is going to be called using @Pointcut, @Before, @Around and @After which methods will be affected by the aspect. For example, method onClickBefore will be executed before someone executes onClickEntryPoint from this class. The JoinPoint argument can be used for different purposes like getting arguments of the method affected by the aspect.

Comment: `aspectj` can't inject code in the body of a method and this seems to be what the OP is asking for.

Comment: why would you like to inject code in the body? Not sure if I understand you correctly, but if you mean to insert a piece of code in the middle of the body, how would you specify that?

Comment: That seems to be what the OP is aksing. At least, that's what s(he) wrote. But perhaps he just didn't know how to properly implement `aspectj`

Comment: plugin `'com.uphyca.gradle:gradle-android-aspectj-plugin:0.9.+'` does not work anymore.

Comment: Does this thing help?
https://github.com/Archinamon/android-gradle-aspectj

Comment: I tried all plugin. I am working on this thing from last 20 days (:

Comment: Ok, let's go one by one :) What about this one: https://github.com/shazam/android-aspects
It seems it could serve the purpose :)